# Azure Application Insights Analytics - Extend new column as second column

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How can I re-order the columns of a analytics query? Specially columns created via "extend"

Comment: Provide your sample query & expected results pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure - you can use the `project` operator. Output columns will be in the order you specify them in the project parameters

Comment: the thing with project is that i have to specify all columns i want... i would like something closer to "Select ColumnA,ColumnB,* from Requests"

Comment: That is not supported AFAIK